# Convert jsonString to something parseable in Python?

Tags: python, json

I'm having trouble converting a jsonString into parseable json in python. My script gets jsonData from a webserver, like so:

```
results = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print results

>>"{\"result\":[{\"0\":\"005d000000450RiAAI\",\"1\":\"003J00000160bqeIAA\",\"2\":\"a09J000000CmRjYIAV\",\"3\":\"Rob Robenson\",\"4\":\"Zac Rosenberg\",\"5\":\"Class IV - Lead\"}, {\"0\":\"005d000000450RiAAI\",\"1\":\"003J0000016ZjuCIAS\",\"2\":\"a09J000000CxvgCIAR\",\"3\":\"Bob Bobenson\",\"4\":\"Zac Rosenberg\",\"5\":\"Class III - Quote/Deal\"}]}"
```

I use json.loads to parse, and get:

```
json_results = json.loads(results.text)
print json_results

>>{"result":[{
               "0":"005d000000450RiAAI",
               "1":"003J00000160bqeIAA",
               "2":"a09J000000CmRjYIAV",
               "3":"Rob Robenson",
               "4":"Zac Rosenberg",
               "5":"Class IV - Lead"
              },
              {
               "0":"005d000000450RiAAI",
               "1":"003J0000016ZjuCIAS",
               "2":"a09J000000CxvgCIAR",
               "3":"Bob Bobenson",
               "4":"Zac Rosenberg",
               "5":"Class III - Quote/Deal"
             }]
  }
```

interestingly enough when i get the type of json_results:

```
print type(json_results)
>>unicode
```

Is that supposed to be the type?

When I try to parse the json, I get:

```
print json_results['result']
>>TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I've tried replacing the '\' in the json string:

```
results = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
results = results.text.replace('\\','')
json_results = json.loads(results)

>>File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/
json/decoder.py", line 368, in decode
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 4 - line 1 column 299 (char 3 - 298)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Thanks everyone!

EDIT: Tried method described in comments:

```
json_results = results.json()
print json_results['result']

>>TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

However,

```
json_results = results.json()
print json_results

>>{"result":[{"0":"005d000000450RiAAI","1":"003J00000160bqeIAA","2":"a09J000000CmRjYIAV","3":"Rob Robenson","4":"Zac Rosenberg","5":"Class IV - Lead"}, {"0":"005d000000450RiAAI","1":"003J0000016ZjuCIAS","2":"a09J000000CxvgCIAR","3":"Bob Bobenson","4":"Zac Rosenberg","5":"Class III - Quote/Deal"}]}
```

This looks good doesn't it? Why won't it parse?

Comment: why not use `result.json()`

Comment: Aha. So can shouldn't be able to just parse the result.text right from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For whatever reason, the server is sending you a JSON document representing a string which is itself a JSON document representing a dictionary - so you'll have to decode it twice:

```
json_results = json.loads(results.json())
```

You can see what's going on a little more clearly with `pprint`:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint

>>> pprint(results.text)
'"{\\"result\\":[{\\"0\\":\\"005d000000450RiAAI\\",\\"1\\":\\"003J00000160bqeIAA\\",\\"2\\":\\"a09J000000CmRjYIAV\\",\\"3\\":\\"Rob Robenson\\",\\"4\\":\\"Zac Rosenberg\\",\\"5\\":\\"Class IV - Lead\\"}, {\\"0\\":\\"005d000000450RiAAI\\",\\"1\\":\\"003J0000016ZjuCIAS\\",\\"2\\":\\"a09J000000CxvgCIAR\\",\\"3\\":\\"Bob Bobenson\\",\\"4\\":\\"Zac Rosenberg\\",\\"5\\":\\"Class III - Quote/Deal\\"}]}"'

>>> pprint(json.loads(results.text))
u'{"result":[{"0":"005d000000450RiAAI","1":"003J00000160bqeIAA","2":"a09J000000CmRjYIAV","3":"Rob Robenson","4":"Zac Rosenberg","5":"Class IV - Lead"}, {"0":"005d000000450RiAAI","1":"003J0000016ZjuCIAS","2":"a09J000000CxvgCIAR","3":"Bob Bobenson","4":"Zac Rosenberg","5":"Class III - Quote/Deal"}]}'

>>> pprint(json.loads(json.loads(results.text)))
{u'result': [{u'0': u'005d000000450RiAAI',
            u'1': u'003J00000160bqeIAA',
            u'2': u'a09J000000CmRjYIAV',
            u'3': u'Rob Robenson',
            u'4': u'Zac Rosenberg',
            u'5': u'Class IV - Lead'},
            {u'0': u'005d000000450RiAAI',
            u'1': u'003J0000016ZjuCIAS',
            u'2': u'a09J000000CxvgCIAR',
            u'3': u'Bob Bobenson',
            u'4': u'Zac Rosenberg',
            u'5': u'Class III - Quote/Deal'}]}
```